# How to process Ajax Data in Python (Django)

Tags: python, ajax, django

I want to push front end data (Form inputs) to the server via Ajax. For this, I created an Ajax post request but I'm very unsteady...
At my first attemps, I constantly receive errors by python

Ajax call:

```
//Get journey time for the stated address
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/termin/get-journey-time/',
        data: {
            'method': 'get_journey_time',
            'mandant_id': 1,
            'customer_address': customer_address,
            'staff_group': staff_group_id
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error")
        },
        timeout: 120000,
    });
```

I've created a view in Python, in which I want to do something (views.py)

```
class get_journey_time(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Handle Ajax Post to calculate the journey time to customer for the selected staff group
    """
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request)
```

In my url route file I have this code lines (urls.py)

```
urlpatterns = [
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    path('termin/get-journey-time/', views.get_journey_time.as_view()),
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
]
```

I got the Error code 500:

```
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

Is there a mistake in my approach, did I miss anything or is it completely crap?

Comment: return `Response` or `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` from the post method

Comment: you can use `from django.http import JsonResponse` for `json` format response

Comment: What is confusing you about that **extremely clear** error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define **renderer classes** and **parser classes** in **settings.py**.

> **Note:** You can define many of these (based on requirements and needs) but here we only need JSON related.
>
> As a reference, you can check my repo's this file https://github.com/hygull/p-host/blob/master/src/pmt_hostel_app/views.py. I have used function based views, just ignore the code inside it and focus on **request.data** and also check related HTML files.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ), 
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer', 
   )
}
```

In this way you will be able to access the posted data in the form of dictionary which can be obtained using **request.data** in views.

Finally, return Response from the post()  method. By default return type of function/method is **None** and you are just printing the **request**.

Check the below mentioned links, it will help you a lot.

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/

In client code, I mean in JavaScript code,  define a **success** callback as well (you have just defined **error** callback).

Please comment, if you are stuck.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question. DRF handles JSON by default anyway, there is no need to set the parser/renderer classes.

Comment: It will handle but in that case, you will not be able to see your posted data in the form of dictionary. If you access **request.data** as I guess. I will check again and update the answer if it is like that.

Comment: Even if we will not set, it will work but what about the case where we want to dump data as JSON just to log request body. So I this setting the classes would be a right approach.

Comment: No problem @aejsi5. Thank you.

Comment: @hygull Sorry for bothering you. If I trie to access the posted ajax data like:
`def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
body = request.POST
`
I receive the error "Unsuported Media Type", Could you pls help?

Comment: How are you posting data client side? Check whether you are  using `JSON.stringify()` and also make sure you have set `Content-Type| header.

Comment: I mean, use `data: JSON.stringify({... })` and also set **headers** property with one of the key **Content-Type** with value **application/json**. This is based on what I guess to solve this. If you are posting images/files etc. then I would be little different and parser & render classes too.

Comment: I had told you to check the link that I have pasted in my answer. For a simple reference you can thpartse code inside https://github.com/hygull/p-host/blob/master/src/pmt_hostel_app/templates/pmt_hostel_app/login.html. Here I have used **fetch()** function, you are using Ajax. So just focus on **headers** and **body** (In case of Ajax it is **data**) parts. And let me know in comment if you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class get_journey_time(APIView):
    # ListAPIView is used for read-only endpoints
    #
    """
    Handle Ajax Post to calculate the journey time to customer for the selected staff group
    """
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # you can get the posted data by request.data
        posted_data = request.data
        data = {"test": "test"}
        return Response(data)
```

you can get the posted data and use serializers. you can start learning playing with serializers [from here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Example serializer code can be like this

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class DummySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    mobile_number = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

and then use it in post method of your `get_journey_time` class